Mongodb query in spring boot taking customised elements
class Cat {
  String _id;
  String name;
  Health health;
}
class Health {
  String id;
  State state;
  String disease;
}
Enum State{
  ACTIVE;
  PASSIVE;
}

Using mongoTemplate for in java spring boot.
List<String> catIds = ArrayList.of("1", "2", "3");

Want all cats in the given list,
also make cat.health = null if cat.health.state = PASSIVE;
My current solution is:
public ArrayList<Cat> getCustomCats(ArrayList<String> catIds)
{
  ArrayList<Cat> catList = new ArrayList();
  mongoTemplate.find(catIds, Cat.class).stream().forEach(cat -> {

    catList.add(cat);
    if(nonNull(cat.getHealth()) && 
      State.PASSIVE.equals(cat.getHealth().getState))
      cat.setHealth(null);
  });
  return catList;
}

Want to achieve this using single query like
return mongoTemplate.someFunction();

